# Django - create new Objects when new user is registered

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a bet app / guessing app. The user can bet on all NFL games and guess the correct result. So I made 4 Models (2 relevant for my current problem):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points   = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)


class Tipp(models.Model):
# model for one gameday (17 gamedays at all)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    week = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    result_hometeam1     = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    result_guestteam1     = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

So there are 16 games every week the user can bet. For this I created a form and implement in the template:

```
class Tipp_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tipp
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
def week(request, pk):
    game = Tipp.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = Tipp_form(initial={'user':request.user, 'week':game}, instance=game)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Tipp_form(request.POST, instance=game)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'main/week.html', {
        'game': game,
        'form': form,
     })
```

everything is working perfectly but now if a new user register I dont want to create 17 new weeks with 16 games every gameday! Is there a way to say: if a new user is logged in, create 17 new objects in Tipp and set user = new User?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use signals for this so that every time a new user is created, new objects for `Tipp` are also created, e.g.:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Tipp

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_picks(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Tipp.objects.create(user=instance)
```